# Dragging Files to NSStatusItem

Tags: objective-c, file-io, nsapplication

I was told that the `application:openFile:` delegate method for NSApp would allow my application to open files by dropping them into the dock, but does this also apply to NSStatusItems in the menu bar? I would like to know before trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

It does not. If you want this behavior, you'll have to roll your own custom view for the status item.